# expected Inputs to have shape (150,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, vectorization

I'm running a keras model but it is showing shape error, although i did check the shape and it is correct.

```
predict = model.predict(sequences_matrix)
```

its showing the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected Inputs to have shape (150,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

when I check its shape, its showing correct one:

```
sequences_matrix.shape
```

output is:

```
(150,)
```

Comment: could you add more information, like `model.summary()`

Answer (score 1):

That is because the first channel is reserved for the batches. The function should work if you reshape your sequence_matrix to (1,150)

```
sequence_matrix = sequence_matrix.reshape(1,-1)
```

Then the model separates the batch of 1 and gets a (150,) input to the model. Right now it is assuming you are passing it 150 batches, each batch with (1,) shape.